# Why can't change my ip? Tor & Python

Tags: python, ip, tor

Hi there I've been trying to change my ip after some requests for scraping a website, but when I run this code which is the one i've found on some blogs, anything happens, I mean my ip is the same in the two outputs. Anyone have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests

def set_new_ip():
    """Change IP using TOR"""
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='my_password')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

local_proxy = '127.0.0.1:8118'
http_proxy = {'http://': local_proxy,
          'https://': local_proxy}

current_ip = requests.get(url='http://icanhazip.com/',
                      proxies=http_proxy,
                      verify=False)

print(current_ip.text)

set_new_ip()

current_ip = requests.get(url='http://icanhazip.com/',
                      proxies=http_proxy,
                      verify=False)

print(current_ip.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i've found a video and solve my question, here it is the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTc8Vqn57pM

and here it is my code

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests
import socks, socket
import time


with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password='my_password')
    socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, addr="127.0.0.1", port=9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    while True:
        current_ip = requests.get(url='http://icanhazip.com/')
        print(current_ip.text)
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        time.sleep(controller.get_newnym_wait())
```